# I get error when i try to install Griddb database

Tags: griddb

I'm trying to install Griddb on Centos 8 by running rpm file:

`sudo rpm -i griddb_nosql-4.3.0-1.linux.x86_64.rpm`

but i get this error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    /usr/bin/python is needed by griddb_nosql-4.3.0-1.linux.x86_64
```

it seems like Griddb can't find python, but python is installed on my computer. I checked if python works by running this command: 
`python -V`

and it works completely  fine, that's why i have no idea what's the problem.

Comment: There is no `/usr/bin/python` in CentOS 8 by default. `rpm -i` will check for files installed from an rpm package. If you created a symlink `python -> python2` it is unknown to the RPM data base.

Comment: Knud Larsen  ok, and what should i do?

Comment: What happens if you install the package with dnf ? I.e. like `# dnf install ./griddb_nosql-4.3.0-1.linux.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: I've tried with `rpm` command only, but ok, I will try to install it with `dnf` command.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running Python 3. According to the page https://github.com/griddb/python_client it mentions the operating environment supported to be Python 3.6

```
$python --version
$python3 --version
```

For me, I have `Python 2.7.18` and `Python 3.7.9` installed. I was able to get the client installed using the command `python3 -m pip install griddb-python` (as root).